# Existence of a linear transformation(geometric)

Tags: linear-algebra

So my professor today asked this question. Is there any linear transformation that sends a square which is symmetric around both axis to a regular hexagons which is also symmetric around axis. I'm quite confused with the question. Any hints would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Linear transforms map entire line segments to line segments. The square consists of 4 line segments and the hexagon consists of 6, therefore no such linear map could exist.

Alternatively, linear transformations preserve parallelness. There are 2 pairs of parallels in a square and 3 in a hexagon, so no linear map could exist